# Jcrop Javascript Image Preview Distorting

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image-resizing, jcrop

I have been trying to implement Jcrop so that when a user uploads their image they are able to crop their image and see what this crop will look like in a preview.

Everything is finally working fine except for the preview which seems to be stretching my images and distorting their width.

The current code I have is as so:

Crop.html.erb

```
<% content_for :head do %>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(function() {
          $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
            onChange: update_crop,
            onSelect: update_crop,
            setSelect: [0, 0, 300, 300],
            aspectRatio: 1
          });
        });

        function update_crop(coords) {
            var rx = 100/coords.w;
            var ry = 100/coords.h;
            var lw = $('#cropbox').width();
            var lh = $('#cropbox').height();
            var ratio = <%= @user.avatar_geometry[:width] %> / lw ;

          $('#preview').css({
            width: Math.round(rx * lw) + 'px',
            height: Math.round(ry * lh) + 'px',
            marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * coords.x) + 'px',
            marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * coords.y) + 'px'
          });
          $("#crop_x").val(Math.round(coords.x * ratio));
          $("#crop_y").val(Math.round(coords.y * ratio));
          $("#crop_w").val(Math.round(coords.w * ratio));
          $("#crop_h").val(Math.round(coords.h * ratio));
        }
    </script>
<% end %>

<%= image_tag @user.avatar_url(:normal), :id => "cropbox" %>

<h3>Preview</h3>
<div class="preview">
    <%= image_tag @user.avatar_url(:thumb), :id => "preview" %>
</div>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <% for attribute in [:crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_h, :crop_w] %>
        <%= f.hidden_field attribute, :id => attribute %>
    <% end %>
    <p><%= f.submit "Crop" %></p>
<% end %>
```

It would be great if anyone knows where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: make sure that the css container of the image preview has no set width and height.  you can actually set only 1 of them and the browser will do the scaling.

Comment: Hi @jvnill, Should I not be setting the height on either width or height? I tried setting just one of these and the image would just increase in size when moving the cropper element. If you have any more advice that would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Hey Tom, sorry. without really looking at the issue and the code, I can't help at all.  If you can create a jsfiddle for this issue, it'd be a big help :)

Comment: Hey Jvnill, Thanks again for your reply. I have managed to half get Jsfiddle to work but am failing to get the Jcrop overlay (really sorry Javascript is not my strength). It's very close to working and can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/4zYgf/42/ I will update the link if I manage to get it working :)

Comment: FYI http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=thumbnail (code from the demo)